# System Keychain Has an Entry that can't be deleted

Tags: iphone, system, distribution, keychain

I'm trying to build my app with xcode and it's throwing a code sign error saying:

```
iPhone Distribution: jetheat: ambiguous (matches "iPhone Distribution: jetheat" in /Library/Keychains/System.keychain and "iPhone Distribution: jetheat" in /Users/Jet/Library/Keychains/login.keychain

Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1
```

So it says that I have two distribution certificates in my keychain, which is true as i can see that in my keychain.

But when I try to delete the certificate within the system keychain, it just wont allow me to do it.

It says:
An error occurred while deleting “iPhone Distribution: jetheat.”
The specified item could not be found in the keychain.

Any ideas what I can do?

Thanks,

JH

Comment: Remove it from login keychain?

Comment: If I remove it from login keychain, the app says that the certificate doesn't exist.

Comment: So I'm trying to remove it from the system keychain instead - which is stubborn.

Comment: Just had to restart keychain and poof, it was gone!